# Layout for touch screen application

Tags: java, swing, layout, touchscreen

I have to develop a touch screen application based on swing for the GUI part.
The application will have to be displayed on different screen, one 15" 4/3 screen and one 20".
What kind of layout stategy should i go for, to keep the same proportion in my components from one screen to another ?
The application will have a kind of status bar at the top displaying some information coming from a server, a menu bar at the bottom, the main central part of the application will display graphs, and on the right an area that will display the same information as the graphs, but in digital format.  Buttons from the menu bar and labels in display/status bar have to be quite big as the users that will play with the screen may wear gloves...
Thanks you for help.

Comment: What does your application do? An RSS reader is going to be laid out out in a very differently from a game.

Answer (score 0):

any specific layout manager is not gonna do the trick....Handling the window size is not a problem as that can be taken care of (use ToolKit for that). Only problem is that u gotta make sure that, the component sizes are not fixed, cos when screen size changes that gotta change as well. This is a peculiar problem, lot of trail and testing may be required.